# Unable to install PHP Nuke

Tags: php, mysql, installation

I am using PHP nuke 7.6

In config.php i have changes the some code -

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuname = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = " phpnuke";
$prefix = "nuke";
$user_prefix = "nuke";
$dbtype = "MySQL";
$sitekey = "SdFk*fa28367-dm56w69.3a2fDS+e9";
$gfx_chk = 0;
$subscription_url = "";
$admin_file = "admin";
```

After complete the configuration i got the following message.

### **"There seems to be a problem with the MySQL server, sorry for the inconvenience. We should be back shortly."**

Please help me to shutout this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your configuration is either incorrect, or the server is not configured as you expect it to be. Can you connect with the `mysql` command-line tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the space before phpnuke in $dbname?

```
$dbname = " phpnuke";
```